# 'cursor_name' does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I wrote following trigger for audit purposes. When I try to update a record in `Sales.SalesOrderHeader` table I get following error:

> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tr_AuditUpdate, Line 11 A
>   cursor with the name 'c_Audit2' does not exist.

This is the trigger:

```
 USE [AdventureWorks2008R2]
    GO
    /****** Object:  Trigger [Sales].[tr_AuditUpdate]    Script Date: 9/19/2016 9:27:36 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER trigger [Sales].[tr_AuditUpdate]
    on [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]
    for Update
    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @EntityCode1 int
    DECLARE @OldStatus1 nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @NewStatus1 nvarchar(100)

    if @@ROWCOUNT>0
        DECLARE c_Audit2 CURSOR LOCAL FOR
        Select  d.SalesOrderID,d.Status,i.Status
        From    deleted AS d
        join inserted AS i
        on i.SalesOrderID=d.SalesOrderID
    Open c_Audit2


    Fetch Next From c_Audit2
    INTO @EntityCode1, @OldStatus1, @NewStatus1

    While @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
      execute sp_Audit @AuditedTable='Sales.SalesOrderHeader',
                       @EntityCode=@EntityCode1,
                       @OldStatus=@OldStatus1,
                       @NewStatus1=@NewStatus1,
                       @AuditUpdate='+',
                       @AuditInsert='-',
                       @AuditDelete='-'

      Fetch Next From c_Audit2
      INTO @EntityCode1, @OldStatus1, @NewStatus1
    END

    CLOSE c_Audit2
    DEALLOCATE c_Audit2
    END
```

This is the update statement

```
update Sales.SalesOrderHeader
set Status=4
where SalesOrderID=43659
```

Comment: one question, why the if @@rowcount>0 in the beginning of the trigger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cursor will only be created if @@ROWCOUNT>0 as you have written in the beginning of the trigger. Remove that if and it will work fine.

```
if @@ROWCOUNT>0
    DECLARE c_Audit2 CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    Select  d.SalesOrderID,d.Status,i.Status
    From    deleted AS d
    join inserted AS i
    on i.SalesOrderID=d.SalesOrderID
open c_Audit2 -- fails when @@rowcount=0
```

because of the if the cursor will not always be created.

then your next statement is

```
open c_Audit2
```

and that will fail if "@@ROWCOUNT>0" returns false

remove this code :     **if @@ROWCOUNT>0** and your trigger will work.